'Spurious convergence' for oscillatory integrals
I am reading the paper

J. N. L. Connor and P. R. Curtis. A method for the numerical evaluation of the oscillatory integrals associated with the cuspoid catastrophes: Application to Pearcey’s integral and its derivatives. J. Phys. A 15, no. 4, pp. 1179–1190  (1982),

and there (in p. 1184), the authors mention the following:

When using a quadrature routine it is important to avoid any spurious numerical convergence to which oscillatory integrals are prone.

Can I ask what this spurious numerical convergence is, when it happens, how to mitigate it, and (most importantly) what are good resources to learn about it?

This is not a full answer to all of your question, but it is too long to be a comment. Spurious convergence typically refers to a situation where the error estimator indicates that an algorithm has converged to the correct solution when, in reality, it has either: (1) converged to an incorrect solution, or (2) failed to converge altogether.
In the context of numerical integration, we want to estimate an integral of a given function $f$. For simplicity, consider a one dimensional integral $I=\int_{a}^bf(x) dx$ on a bounded interval $|a|,|b|<\infty$. In theory, a simple Riemann sum is guaranteed to converge to the integral as the number of terms tends to $\infty$ provided the function is nice enough. However, sometimes are interested in approximating the integral within a specific tolerance.
The basic idea is the following: Say you want to approximate $I$ with an accuracy $\varepsilon>0$, we use two approximations: $I'$ and $I''$ where $I''$ is better than $I'$: If $|I''-I'|<\varepsilon$, we stop. Else, we obtain an even better approximation $I'''$ and repeat this process with $I''$ and $I'''$.
Note here that we are hoping that $|I''-I'|<\varepsilon$ will result in  $|I''-I|<\varepsilon$ (or $<2\varepsilon$). However, this is not always the case (Hence, a situation of spurious convergence). To see this in action, see the following two examples:

Example 1: (From Methods of Numerical Integration, p. 423)  Patterson's rules are a sequence of quadrature rules with an increasing number of nodes. The nodes and weights can be found here. Now, consider the integral $\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx$, where
$$f(x)=\frac{\exp(-6.793x^2)}{1.000001-x^2},$$
If we use the 7-point and the 15-point Patterson rule, we observe that they agree to 6 decimal points (when rounded) but the actual error is $\sim 10^{-2}$. If you want to experiment with this, see the following Julia code.
#Nodes and weights: 
#  https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/f_src/patterson_rule/patterson_rule.html
w=[0.1700171962994026E-01
         0.5160328299707974E-01
         0.9292719531512454E-01
         0.1344152552437842    
         0.1715119091363914    
         0.2006285293769890    
         0.2191568584015875    
         0.2255104997982067    
         0.2191568584015875    
         0.2006285293769890    
         0.1715119091363914    
         0.1344152552437842    
         0.9292719531512454E-01
         0.5160328299707974E-01
         0.1700171962994026E-01
       ]
x=[ -0.9938319632127550    
       -0.9604912687080203    
       -0.8884592328722570    
       -0.7745966692414834    
       -0.6211029467372264    
       -0.4342437493468025    
       -0.2233866864289669    
         0.000000000000000    
        0.2233866864289669    
        0.4342437493468025    
        0.6211029467372264    
        0.7745966692414834    
        0.8884592328722570    
        0.9604912687080203    
        0.9938319632127550   ]


w7=[0.104656226026467265194
        0.268488089868333440729
        0.401397414775962222905
        0.450916538658474142345
        0.401397414775962222905
        0.268488089868333440729
        0.104656226026467265194]

f(x)=exp(-6.793*(x^2))/(1.000001-x^2)

x7=x[2:2:end]


w7'*f.(x7) #0.7536572406652909
w'*f.(x)   #0.7536566838282481

This might give you the impression that the integral is $\approx 0.75365$ but the exact value of integral is $\approx 0.7624167$.
using QuadGK #Gauss-Konrod adaptive quadrature.
quadgk(f,-1,1,atol=1E-13) #(value,error)=(0.7624167932894478, 9.09084548091077e-14)


Example 2: (Manufactured example) At the end of the previous example, I have used a Gauss-Konrod adaptive quadrature which outperformed the Patterson method. However, we can manufacture an example where GK suffers from spurious convergence too. For example, we take $f$ to be one at all of the 15 GK nodes:
using QuadGK
import QuadGK:wd7,wgd7,xd7 #nodes and weights

x15=[xd7;-xd7[end-1:-1:1]]
w15=[wd7;wd7[end-1:-1:1]]

g(x)=exp(prod(abs(x-node) for node in x15)) # g(x)=1 if x is a GK node

quadgk(g,-1,1,atol=1E-13) # returns: (2.0, 0.0)

Here, quadgk is very confident that the integral is equal to 2.0 (at least in double precision) but we know for a fact that the integral is $>2$ by construction of $g$, see the graph below

A better approximation would be
quadgk(g,-1,0,atol=1E-13)[1]+quadgk(g,0,1,atol=1E-13)[1] #2.000075120496727


If you want more resources, see Methods of Numerical Integration. Chapter 6 contains a more involved discussion of spurious convergence with more examples and multiple references.
